# What can expired Goodberries be used for?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

We are playing out of the abyss and every day I make excess Goodberries and have been storing them in a pouch. I'm not sure what to use them for.

I was hoping to form balls of them squished together and used them as a weapon to throw at people.

There was also talks about mixing them with water and forming a type of mortar.

Looking for any thoughts on this topic as I don't like to waste extra Goodberries.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it's probably inappropriate for this site, given that any good answer is going to be highly opinion-based, or else depend on the permissiveness of the DM. You might better off taking this question to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat), or to another forum or Reddit.

Comment: Fair enough, it seemed very opinion-based but I figured I'd ask and see if someone had come across something I couldn't find.

Comment: What is the reason for finding an application for berries specifically? Aside from your spells and equipment, any part of the environment can be exploited — you can grab a pinch of sand and throw it into your foe's face, you can throw stones, etc. Why berries?

Comment: On RPG.SE you should only [ask practical, answerable questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) based on actual problems that you face. What problem are you trying to solve by reusing the expired berries? Instead of speculations "how non-magical berries can be used", maybe we could help with the very problem.

Comment: Yeah that was my mistake, I read the rules for this SE carefully but at this point I'm going to leave the question up, but wont have any issue with the mods removing it. The only goal was first confirm that they remain as normal berries after they expire. The secondary goal was to find a way to use non-magical berries which is obviously the opinion based part. If I had just looked to confirm that they turn into non-magical berries it probably would have been a proper question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## The berries are non-magical after the first day

Expired Goodberries are good for all the same things a regular berry is. The only common use for berries aside from being eaten is in the forming of dyes. Perhaps your DM would allow you to create berry dye.

A mushy berry ball is unlikely to be an effective weapon or any kind of glue or mortar.

Comment: Ok. If it's basically similar to any normal berry excluding any usefulness another berry might have in regards to nutrition, I can work with that. It wasn't might to be a useful weapon. More like shove/shoot it into someones face and blind them for a moment.

Comment: I would expect them to disappear since the description makes the spell a conjuration rather than the transmutation it is classified as.

Comment: @Slagmoth they are specifically described as "losing their potency" when the spell ends, which strongly implies their physical form remains

Comment: @SirCinnamon Oh, I understand that part. But it again alludes to it being a transmutation instead of a conjuration. Always used to have existing berries to cast the spell on, if that were still the case having left over berries makes sense. Apologies, I am just nit-picking the dev oversight on this spell.

Comment: We are in the underdark and I just make tons of extra berries now. Was just looking for another fun use for them. Nothing special.

Comment: Or as a garnish for a meal; depending upon how in depth the RP is at the table, a berry is still a food, albeit no longer a magical food.

Comment: If you have DM willing to work with you, potentially ammunition for Magic Stone!

By raw no, but I could see it be an interesting if not fun use of an otherwise underused cantrip.